# Delete the object through tridion core service

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am not able to delete the object through core service.

I am getting object reference not found error. I am able to create and get the object but delete functionality fails.

I am using this code:

```cs
var client = new CoreService2010Client();
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = Settings.UserID;
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = Settings.Password;
client.Open();
client.Delete(TCMURI);
```

here's the error:

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ICoreService.Delete(String id)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.CoreServiceClient.Delete(String id)
   at TridionCoreService.Program.testing() in C:\WORK\My Work\TridionCoreService\TridionCoreService\Program.cs:line 125
   at TridionCoreService.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\WORK\My Work\TridionCoreService\TridionCoreService\Program.cs:line 25
```

---

I am using above code only and pass the tcm URI

Error Code : {System.ServiceModel.FaultCode}

Comment: What object are you trying to delete? Is that object in a published state? What is the error message?

Comment: i am trying to delete the page and page is not publish Error: Object Reference not found.

Comment: that's a rather general error, could be anything.
Could you post some more code, or a stacktrace?

Comment: Do you have UGC installed? Check the Windows Event log on the Content Manager Server for a more detailed error message.

Comment: has anyone tried this? Because I get the same error when calling client.Delete("tcm:114-506727");

Comment: I've added some more error info. The error is thrown right at the Delete method...

Comment: I had the same error and it was related to UGC. I disabled UGC (commented out the model and editor in the config and the eventsystem.dll from ugc), restarted the server and everything worked. Check the 'Tridion' Windows Event Log on the Content Manager Server. There is probably an error related to UGC. I think you need to contact CS to fix this, since the error is in the Eventsystem dll from UGC

Comment: great work Albert, UGC errors are present in the Event log.
I guess I'll have to contact CS then...

Comment: @Albert: can you enter your suggestion as an answer, so that Shekhar can accept it (if he was affected by the same problem as Reinder)?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error and it was related to UGC. 
I disabled UGC (commented out the model and editor in the config and the eventsystem.dll from ugc), restarted the server and everything worked.

Check the 'Tridion' Windows Event Log on the Content Manager Server. There is probably an error related to UGC. I think you need to contact CS to fix this, since the error is in the Eventsystem dll from UGC